# Get output of InventorServer Engine as stp file or should I use ModelDerivative API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

Referring to the attached image taken from today's webinar:
(could someone with at least 10 reputation post this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dzgp.png)

Once, for example, changed parameters, could my appPackage (i.e. changeParamsPlugin) do something like this?

`doc.SaveAs(Path.GetDirectoryName(doc.FullDocumentName) + "\\" + outputFile + ".stp", True);`

and then file be downloaded like this:

`DownloadToDocs(resultUrl, AppProperties.OutputFile + AppProperties.StepExtension); // Output to MyDocuments`

Or afterwards should I use model derivative API to translate output in a step file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note on this is that Inventor in Design Automation is currently in Private Beta so using this in production is not currently available. If you're interested in exploring our private beta please contact me.

As far as guidance goes for this question, in general translations should be done with the ModelDerivative API in Forge. If you need "custom" work done prior to a translation then using Design Automation is the right way to go.

The AutoCAD "Engine" is available in production for Design Automation, while what you list above is the presentation I gave today with the disclaimer that this is not available in production.